# Drupal 7 Taxonomy Multiselect box size

Tags: drupal-7, admin, drupal-taxonomy

I have couple of taxonomies that have few hundred terms in. A content type has multiple of these taxonomy multiselect boxes.

Problem is, that select box size is about 5 (so it shows only 5 at the time). How can i increase the size? Because now treelike use is impossible, because you won't see parent after you've scrolled a bit back.

The problem is in the admin / editor view, and are not related to end-user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really about the height of that select box, why don't you add it via CSS?

```
#your-form-id .form-select[multiple] {
  height: 300px;
}
```

Alternatively, implement [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in your module:

```
<?php
  function YOURMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['YOURFIELD']['#size'] = 30;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried any of these?

https://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree
https://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select
https://drupal.org/project/multiselect

edit - ah ok I'll explain:

OP asked a question about changing sizes of select boxes because there were hundreds of options available and hinted at hierarchy issues in their post. The above modules provide more rich interfaces for users to select multiple options, hence why I listed them. I shall explain more next time soz!

Comment: link only answers are not appreciated on SO. Please add some explanation, as why would you suggest OP to use those link or what is in those links that will help or some code snippet.